# Devise, Omniauth and Twitter

Tags: ruby, devise, twitter-oauth, omniauth

I'm working on a Rails 3 app that uses devise and omniauth and followed the examples given in https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview and it worked well for Facebook accounts, but when I tried adding Twitter auth, I get a '401 Unauthorized' response.  To track the problem down I switched the URL for api.twitter.com to http and dumped the network traffic and it looks like it's POSTing to /oauth/access_token twice.  The first time I get a 200 response, the second gives the 401.  In between it successfully gets user info for the authenticated user using 'GET /1/account/verify_credentials.json' method.  I don't understand why the code calls the access_token method the second time.

In my config/initializers/devise.rb file I added:

```
config.omniauth :twitter, "consumer_key", "consumer_secret"
```

in addition to the rest of the code outlined in the Omniauth overview page above.

I also added a 'twitter' method in my OmniauthCallbacksController, but it never gets called due to the 401.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check your twitter function in OmniauthCallbacksController? devise will throw invalid response error if there's error , you can try to dump response by render :text => env["omniauth.auth"] in your controller

Answer (score 7):

Try with filling Callback URL in settings of your application on dev.twitter.com. Should be something like that:

Callback URL http://yousite.com/auth/twitter/callback

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you figured this out or not in the end - but Twitter doesn't support `localhost` domains.

You can get around this by setting up a local alias in `/etc/hosts` and then entering it in the callback URL on Twitter or by putting your site on on an outwards facing server.

As above - the callback should be in the format:

http://mysite/auth/twitter/callback

Comment: You can also use http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback as your callback URL on the twitter side. They don't allow "localhost", but do allow the 127.0.0.1 equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using omniauth-twitter gem??

Problem could be because of callback URL.

in development mode you can se callback url as

http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, because enable :confirmable
I decided to skip confirmation for oauth users: auth.user.skip_confirmation!
And it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem, but ended up getting this to work by removing the `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` file. It doubles up on the requests because you set this up in the `config/initializers/devise.rb`