# Could not authenticate you from Linkedin because "Invalid credentials"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, omniauth, linkedin-api

I have set up DEVISE and OMNIAUTH login. It was working with Facebook. Now I am trying to set it up similarly for LinkedIn. Below is what I have done. However, I am getting following error message - "Could not authenticate you from Linkedin because "Invalid credentials"." Can someone please assist?

Thank you in advance. In case you need more details then let me know.

GEM FILE

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
```

Omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedin, LINKEDIN_APP, LINKEDIN_SECRET
end
```

Devise.rb

```
require "omniauth-linkedin"
config.omniauth :linkedin, LINKEDIN_APP, LINKEDIN_SECRET
```

Where did the get the keys?

1. Registered a new application at https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer?newapp=
2. Got two keys API Key and Secret Key on application show page. Copied them to LINKEDIN_APP, LINKEDIN_SECRET

Comment: Invalid Credentials seems like user error. Your browser might have cached an invalid password. Clear your linked in cookies and try again.

Comment: Does not help. -- I cleaned cache and cookies, signed out of LinkedIn and then tried again. Still got same error.

Comment: @Pykih have you managed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had almost the same problem with 'omniauth-github' . I hope [this](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/04/whodunit-devise-omniauth-oauth-or-github/)  post of Ryan Bigg is going to help you. Another simple check is if url and url-callback of the app are there (no localhost:3000 allowed) .

Answer (score 0):

`omniauth.rb` is conflicting with `devise.rb` as both are interacting with Omniauth. Remove the code in `omniauth.rb`.

Explained in Devise documentation:

[Remember that config.omniauth adds omniauth provider middleware to your application. This means you should not add this provider middleware again in config/initializers/omniauth.rb as they'll clash with each other and result in always-failing authentication.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)

Similar questions:

[Rails: Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "Invalid credentials"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176208/rails-could-not-authenticate-you-from-facebook-because-invalid-credentials)

[Authentication failure : Devise + OmniAuth + Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396233/authentication-failure-devise-omniauth-twitter)