# Devise with Omniauth. Could not authenticate because "Invalid credentials"."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I am having trouble integrating Devise with an Omniauth provider. I have Doorkeeper set up on an external server however it was returning Invalid credentials when it returned to my local application which I have set up with pow.

For the sake of debugging I have now decided just to focus on twitter authentication - Which also seems to fail in my local rails app.

I have been following this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised (Still with no luck) - As I have tried to integrate with twitter with still no luck.

I have created an Omniauth initializer:

> Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
>     provider :twitter, "my twitter app id", "My Twitter secret"
>   end

and in my devise initializer:

> config.omniauth :twitter, ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"], ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]

I have told configured devise with

> :omniauthable

My application successfully gets to twitter to authenticate however when it returns.. the log on my local application is as follows:

> Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
>     Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"A VALID AUTH TOKEN", "oauth_verifier"=>"A VALID TOKEN"}
>   Redirected to My local URL

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authentication failure : Devise + OmniAuth + Twitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396233/authentication-failure-devise-omniauth-twitter)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have a scope at the end of your Devise setup

`config.omniauth :twitter, 'ID', 'SECRET', {:scope => 'offline_access,email'}`

Comment: He's using Twitter, not Facebook.